# How to auto generate multiple buttons in the following format

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering how can I create these buttons. All the timing is dynamic and is received from a server, also the number of buttons will vary.
It would be a big help if some one can provide me with some directions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the list items and build a grid and wrap the gridtiles with an Inkwell... You can achieve any user input action with onTap() or longpress()